# class llvm::MCInstPrinter’ has no member named ‘setPrintBranchImmAsAddress

Tags: compiler-errors, llvm, riscv

When I use compile a project about riscv32 in wsl2(Windows Subsystem for Linux)with linux version ubuntu-20.04LTS, it occurs a compile wrong:

```
chizm@LAPTOP-UV3G5VIL:~/Templates/ics2021/nemu$ make
+ CXX src/utils/disasm.cc
src/utils/disasm.cc: In function ‘void init_disasm(const char*)’:
src/utils/disasm.cc:55:8: error: ‘class llvm::MCInstPrinter’ has no member named ‘setPrintBranchImmAsAddress’
   55 |   gIP->setPrintBranchImmAsAddress(true);
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [/home/chizm/Templates/ics2021/nemu/scripts/build.mk:40: /home/chizm/Templates/ics2021/nemu/build/obj-riscv32-nemu-interpreter/src/utils/disasm.o] Error 1
```

but I ckeck my llvm version below:

```
chizm@LAPTOP-UV3G5VIL:~/Templates/ics2021/nemu$ sudo apt install llvm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
llvm is already the newest version (1:10.0-50~exp1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

LLVM version is latest. How should I do?

Here is the code:

```
#include "llvm/MC/MCAsmInfo.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCContext.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCDisassembler/MCDisassembler.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCInstPrinter.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"

using namespace llvm;

static llvm::MCDisassembler *gDisassembler = nullptr;
static llvm::MCSubtargetInfo *gSTI = nullptr;
static llvm::MCInstPrinter *gIP = nullptr;

extern "C" void init_disasm(const char *triple) {
  llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos();
  llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs();
  llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers();
  llvm::InitializeAllDisassemblers();

  std::string errstr;
  std::string gTriple(triple);

  llvm::MCInstrInfo *gMII = nullptr;
  llvm::MCRegisterInfo *gMRI = nullptr;
  auto target = llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(gTriple, errstr);

....

  gDisassembler = target->createMCDisassembler(*gSTI, *Ctx);
  gIP = target->createMCInstPrinter(llvm::Triple(gTriple),
      AsmInfo->getAssemblerDialect(), *AsmInfo, *gMII, *gMRI);
  gIP->setPrintImmHex(true);
  gIP->setPrintBranchImmAsAddress(true);

....
}
```

Additionally, My cpu of computer is AMD64

Answer (score 1):

I see setPrintBranchImmAsAddress() is added from llvm-11, chances are you're using an older version. Try to install with version number as shown [here](https://apt.llvm.org/)

```
# LLVM
apt-get install libllvm-13-ocaml-dev libllvm13 llvm-13 llvm-13-dev llvm-13-doc llvm-13-examples llvm-13-runtime
# Clang and co
apt-get install clang-13 clang-tools-13 clang-13-doc libclang-common-13-dev libclang-13-dev libclang1-13 clang-format-13 python-clang-13 clangd-13
```

Comment: I update the llvm-10 to llvm-13. However, the default version of llvm in ubuntu 20.04 is llvm-10. So When I code ```#include "llvm/MC/MCDisassembler/MCDisassembler.h"```，error occurs: ``` fatal error: llvm/MC/MCAsmInfo.h: No such file or directory```. How should I do to make the system regard the llvm as llvm-13

Comment: use apt remove and  apt purge to remove llvm-10

Comment: I have uninstall llvm-10, but the error still exists. And /usr/bin dictionary only has llvm-13

Comment: try running make VERBOSE=1 and see whether the include dirs contain MCDisassembler.h

Answer (score 1):

My platform is ubuntu 20.04
Here's how I solved it

```
sudo apt autoremove llvm-10
sudo apt install llvm-12
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/llvm-12/bin/llvm-config  llvm-config
```

and then go back to nemu

```
make
```

Answer (score 0):

it is llvm version issue, need update llvm to 11 or above.
I have the same problem, my solution as follows:

1. remove the installed llvm.
2. install llvm 11 or above version use:

   ```
    wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
    chmod +x llvm.sh
    sudo ./llvm.sh <version number>
   ```
3. create a soft link for llvm, my version is 13

   ```
    cd /usr/bin
    ln -s llvm-config-13 llvm-config
   ```
4. make the nemu again

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem in PA0. I installed  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1050-raspi aarch64) on my Raspberry Pi.
You may try this:

```
sudo apt-get automove llvm     # uninstall llvm
sudo apt-get install llvm-11   # install version 11
```

Comment: This is an English-language site. Please translate your answer, if it is an answer at all. (Machine translation suggests this may be more of a speculation.)